# Angular2 Get Routings Map

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How can I get all the routings I have in all my components?
(Like a tree of all my route options)
I am not sure if the right way is to go over the router config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load routes dynamically you can maintain the list of routes yourself:

```ts
export const ROUTES = [
    {path:'/first', name: 'First', component: FirstComponent},
    {path:'/second', name: 'Second', component: SecondComponent}
]

export class App {
  constructor(private _router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._router.config(ROUTES);
  }
}
```

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6908